# Problem while including custom framework in Project

Tags: cocoa, frameworks, dyld

I am trying to learn how to create custom frameworks and use them in a project in cocoa, so I began with a simple custom framework named - SimpleFramework.

It contains one class with only one class method:

```
// class name: SimpleClass, role: Public

+ (void)displayMessage{
    NSLog(@"Hello World");
}
```

I also set its Installation Directory path to - **@executable_path/../Frameworks** then compiled it.

I included it in another project - SimpleTest, using following steps-

1. Dragged SimpleFramework.framework into Frameworks folder in project. Also selected Copy items to destination group's folder and Add To Targets check box.
2. Created a New Copy Files Build Phase. Selected its destination as Frameworks.
3. Dragged SimpleFramework.framework into it.

> Problem is, when I am trying to import
>   SimpleClass.h in SimpleTestAppDelegate
>   class, it is giving this error message
>   on compilation-
>
> SimpleClass.h: No such file or
>   directory.

Can anyone suggest me if I am doing anything wrong?

Code for application can be found here- [Sample code link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9999259/SimpleTest.zip)

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: This question is wonderful. I'm a beginner at XCode and was completely lost until I found your sample code. Now I'm able to add a custom framework. Your three line explanation is a golden teardrop haiku compared to the Framework Programming Guide. 

I just have one question remaining: In your framework, after adding that class and building, how did you arrive at the proper directory structure. I made a framework project, included a class + headers, and built... but after following the steps above MyFramework.framework doesn't actually contain any files. Thanks again! :)

Comment: this is because you need to reset the role of file in framework as public :) ......  that's why it is always better to go through the documentations ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found its solution. I was missing this line:

```
#import "SimpleFramework/SimpleClass.h"
```